Android webview app crash - MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed
I have used WebView for load my webpage but anytime app crash without any error, just return below message.
InputDispatcher  system_server  E  channel '27313a2 com.abc.demo/com.abc.demo.Activitys.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

can anyone please help me.
